# How to multiply several fields in a tuple by a given field of the tuple

Tags: apache-pig

For each row of data, I would like to multiply fields 1 through N by field 0. The data could have hundreds of fields per row (or a variable number of fields for that matter), so writing out each pair is not feasible. Is there a way to specify a range of fields, sort of like the the following (incorrect) snippet?

```
A = LOAD 'foo.csv' USING PigStorage(','); 
B = FOREACH A GENERATE $0*($1,..);
```

Answer (score 0):

A [UDF](http://wiki.apache.org/pig/UDFManual) could come in handy here.

Implement exec(Tuple input) and iterate over all fields of the tuple as follows (not tested):

```
public class MultiplyField extends EvalFunc<Long> {
    public Long exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null || input.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
        Long retVal = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
            Long j = (Long)input.get(i);
            retVal *= j;
        }
        return retVal;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw WrappedIOException.wrap("Caught exception processing input row ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then register your UDF and call it from your FOREACH.